# How to get the actual object of StaticResource from codebehind without using TryFindResource?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, staticresource

I have used a `StaticResource` in *XAML* file. I have named the `StaticResource` using `x:Name`. Now I want to access the actual object of the `StaticResource`.

Here are the files:

**In XAML file:**

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
        ...
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="MyButtonResource" x:Name="MyResource" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**In Code-behind CS file:**

```
Button buttonFromStaticResource = MyResource.SomeProperty as Button;
```

Here, I need something like `SomeProperty` or any method to get the actual object (in this case, it is a `Button` object).

**Edit:**

A way to get the object is to use `TryFindResource`:

```
Button buttonFromStaticResource = this.TryFindResource("MyButtonResource") as Button;
```

But this solution involves a string parameter. Any better solution than this so that I can use `MyResource` directly (by leveraging `x:Name` in XAML file), without using any string?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why the Button is a resource? That's unusual and may lead to problems when you want to use it multiple times. Why not create a Button Style resource?

Comment: @Clemens: Actually in real case, I didn't use a button as resouce. It is just a simplified example.

Answer (score 0):

How to read static Resource in c#, Check a below code

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
        ...
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="MyButtonResource" x:Name="MyResource" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

c#

```
var currentResources= this.Resources["MyButtonResource"];
```

Comment: Edited my question. I actually want a solution which directly uses `MyResource` (by leveraging `x:Name` in XAML file), without using any string.